# Match merge SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables:

`A` with columns:

```
ID  NAME  JOB      ZIP1
--  ----  -------  -----
1   XYZZ  Painter  74075
2   ABCC  ZYZZZ    78754
```

`B` with columns:

```
ZIP    ROLE
-----  ---------
74075  assistant
78754  asstnt2
```

I need the following output

```
ID  NAME  JOB  ZIP  ROLE
--  ----  ---  ---  ----
```

The role value should be appended based on the ZIP value.

Comment: If this is your first time here, you should take a look at the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page. You will get better answers and a lot more people willing to help if you also explain what you have tried, in this instance it would be beneficial to see any queries you have tried. In this instance it's very simple and you've already got two answers, however it will help you in the future. Happy programming =]

Comment: Added data in the question

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.JOB, A.ZIP, B.ROLE
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.ZIP = B.ZIP
```

Comment: I have done a inner join but I am getting duplicate values, How do I eliminate that?

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` after the `SELECT` but this isn't a recommended fix.  Is there a better relation between those 2 tables that you could make?

Comment: The table A is the parent table which has ZIP code values, I need to lookup for ZIP code values from table B and append the value of ROLE to table A

Comment: Which table are you getting your duplicate values in, table A? And by appended do you mean you want a list of roles in one column, e.g. 'Supervisor,Manager,Director'? If I understand your data, you should be seeing duplicates from table A, however this makes sense as there is a one-to-many relationship between ZIP code and roles. Could you add some sample data to your question? You can change the values in the columns if the data is sensitive but it would help if we could see an example of your data.

Answer (score 0):

You need an  [inner join](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

```
SELECT A.ID, A.NAME, A.JOB, A.ZIP, B.ROLE
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B  ON A.ZIP = B.ZIP
```